# Config Column on Design page of Devexpress Gridcontrol Master-Detail Objects List,

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to use List of objects to do Data Binding with GridCountrol,
I find out a sample code of for doing this,

I wonder if I use this way to bind data could I still use the designer to set the column

The gridView2 showing column is different from what I setting as the pictures I attached.

The setting of the detail view columns
[image]

The actually showing columns of the detail view
[image]

How could I make the showing column as My designer setting?

Thanks

This is my sample
[code](https://send.firefox.com/download/cc0f91d4326f8443/#u5uKhKNM5AWUZ3xyvVJKIQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply gridView2 to a collection property, change the level name (Level1) to the collection property name (GPEstaciones).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference ?

the designer only show the content in the xxx.designer.cs

If you run another code out of `InitializeComponent()` method,It will change also.

you can debug and compare the property in runtime and designer.cs

And you can paste your bind code in your problem.